# CSS Height 100% isn't working

Tags: php, css, height

Alright I know this has been asked a million time and I have seen a million answers about the body and html tags needing to be a height of 100% for it to work but I cannot get this thing to work. Here it is the problem:

I need my body inside and sidebar content to extend down to meet the other wherever the other stops. I need this for dynamic pages for wordpress. So here is the header.

**header.php**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
!!!!content cut to save space!!!!!
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="site">

    <div id="wrapper">

            <!------break-from-header------>

            <div id="wrapperbody">
                <div id="bodyinside">
```

The index.php pages and post.php pages anything with content are calling the header above and footer below. Self explanatory right?

**footer.php**

```
                </div><!--body-inside-->
<div id="sidebar">

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<div id="sidebarlight">
</div>
</div>
            </div><!--wrapper-body-->
        </div><!--main-wrapper-->
    <div id="footer-wrapper">
        <div id="footer">

    <div id="footer-nav">

                <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'footer-menu')); ?>

            </div><!--footer-nav-->

            <div id="copyright">

                <p>Powered by: <a href="http://wordpress.org">WordPress</a> Copyright 2013</p>

            </div><!--copyright-->

        </div><!--footer-->

    </div><!--footer-wrapper-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and Finally the css

```
/******************************Basic CSS**************************************/
html,
body {
    background-image:url('http://patriotvoice.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center; 
    color: #000;
    font-family: 12pt/12pt 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    height:100%
    line-height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    }
/*********************************Wrappers********************************/
#site {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
/*****************Main Body******************/
#wrapperbody {
    display: block;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 70px;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
#bodyinside {
    display: inline;
    background: #fff;
    width:740px;
    height: 100%;
    float:left
}
/**************Sidebar******************/
#sidebar-wrapper {
    display: inline;
    background: #2E2E2E;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 340px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I took out a lot of code but that is the basic stuff. Like I said I need the sidebar and body inside to align with one another. You can see where the content extends past the sidebar and I need the grey to extend down to meet with the white here http://patriotvoice.net..... BUT I need the white to  extend down to the grey on a page like this http://patriotvoice.net/news

Comment: You should include a fiddle without the PHP so it's easier to diagnose the problem :)

Comment: `height: 100%;` will not work unless the parent element has a defined height in px or em, but not in %. This is because the the `HTML` or `body` elements are considered the parent elements of everything. Saying that they should be 100% of the height of the page, which is determined by their height, doesn't mean anything because they will always be as big as the content inside of them unless you set a fixed value for them. Think about it this way, the content will grow, as will the parent element, unless a fixed value is set to cap them.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should use `min-height:100%;` for all wraps and contents, because u gave body and html tags `height:100%;`
// sorry, probably I didn´t read your problem well, I'm trying harder with my English but with no significant result

Answer (score 0):

Well first off the site given is looking weird because of the position: fixed on the nav-main-wrapper. Your content is being pushed upwards because of that.

For better coding practices have a header.php, content.php(with the loop), sidebar.php, footer.php to call to the index.

Your height should work fine according it the content you put in it.

Post an example of how it looks with more content for me to better understand how the height:100% isn't working so I can further assist you.